# SQL to filter the data from inner query based on 2 conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, correlated-subquery, in-subquery

I have the following table named `TableB`:

| Datetime | Partid |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z | Part-A |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-B |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-B |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-A |
| 2022-12-24T15:24:00.782Z | Part-B |
| 2022-12-24T15:25:00.782Z | Part-A |

I have another table named `TableA`:

| Datetime | Partid | Customer ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-A |
| 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-B |
| 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-C |
| 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-D |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-D | CUSTOMER-E |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-F |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-G |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-H |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-I |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-E | CUSTOMER-J |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-F | CUSTOMER-K |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-D | CUSTOMER-L |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-M |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-N |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-C | CUSTOMER-O |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-P |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-Q |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-E | CUSTOMER-R |

I would like to exclude the data present in `TableA` based on `Partid` AND `Datetime` in `TableB`.

I want the list of `CustomerID` from TableA based on ONLY those Part-A & Part-B Partid's which ONLY fall between DateTime 2022-12-24T15:20:00.782Z and 2022-12-22T15:22:00.782Z in TableB.

The desired output is:

| Datetime | Partid | Customer ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-24T15:21:00.782Z | Part-D | CUSTOMER-E |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-E | CUSTOMER-J |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-F | CUSTOMER-K |
| 2022-12-24T15:22:00.782Z | Part-D | CUSTOMER-L |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-N |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-C | CUSTOMER-O |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-A | CUSTOMER-P |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-B | CUSTOMER-Q |
| 2022-12-24T15:23:00.782Z | Part-E | CUSTOMER-R |

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different database products. Which one do you use?

Comment: Please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write yourself and explain exactly where you are having an issue

Comment: for SQL help it's always important to mention the database management system you are using as the solution will differ based on that information. So please specify, if you are using MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle or whatever else.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important. Also please note that this site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello All, Please accept my sincere apologies for the things that I missed here. I'm new to this site as well as to SQL. The idea of raising this question was to get some logical direction from SQL experts toward solving this tricky issue. The intent was NEVER to get a SQL Query. Otherwise, I'll never be able to learn SQL(again, my apology for not mentioning this in my question). The database is SQL Server. Once again, Thank You All for taking your time and responding to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH TableCTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.Partid as 'BId'
FROM #TableA a
LEFT JOIN #TableB b ON a.Partid = b.Partid AND a.Datetime=b.Datetime
)

Select * from TableCTE where Bid is NULL
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, Sir, for your response. I understand the logic you're trying in your query. I will try it, play around with it, and update you with my results. Once again, Thank You. I appreciate your help.